# center a variable width p element

Tags: css

How can I center a variable width p element in a div?

It's easy to center a fixed width block element using `margin: 0px auto;`. But how can I set the width of this p element to exactly contain its child, while keeping it as a `block` which is necessary for margins to work?

HTML

```
<div>
 <p>Center me</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width: 300px;
}

p {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AaVjh/)**

`p` is a `block` element and when you put in another block element:

```
<div>
    <p>Center me</p>
</div>
```

The `width` of it, will be the width of parent (with your CSS, `300px`).
The rule `margin: 0 auto;` or more clear, setting `auto` for `margin-left` and `margin-right`,
will put the **element itself** center of the parent.

So when the `parent` and `child` have the same width, it's meanless.

If you want, you can make center the text within it with `text-align` property,
and in your case, you can use `margin` for your `div` element (if its parent is `body` for example):

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Center me</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

And in CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

Also you can make your `p` element as `inline-block` and make `text-align: center;` for the parent:

```
body {
    background: gray;
}

div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
}

p {    
    display: inline-block;
    background: pink;
}
```

[image]

- Check the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AaVjh/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMrF4/)

```
p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: p is not wrapping to it's content here :).